# What's the correct way to do IN (date-range) in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

What's the correct way to do this in Postgres?

```
delete from days where date IN ("2014-02-15", "2014-02-07", 
                                "2014-02-08", "2014-02-09", "2014-03-01");


ERROR -- : PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "2014-02-15" does not exist
```

works fine in MySQL and Sqlite3

Comment: What datatype is `date`?

Comment: the type and the name of the column is `date`

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `IN` statement should be correct BUT don't use `"` for strings as you do and PostgreSQL is complaining about. `"` is used for tables, columns and other objects whereas strings are quoted by `'`.

However, you could also use the `between` clause ...

```
WHERE date between <first_date> and <last_date>
```

Comment: MySQL is not taking care of the SQL standard here, which sucks and ends up in a lot of these errors.

Comment: can't use simple date comparison with `where` .. unfortunately I need specific hand-picked dates